# How do you acquire an exclusive lock on an object within an Apex before insert trigger?

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger

Inside an Apex `before insert` trigger, what is the correct way to get an exclusive lock all records of a particular object for the length of the trigger's transaction?

This trigger needs an exclusive lock to perform validation that can't easily be expressed any other way. The canonical example I see is to check for overlapping dates in a record. Plenty of questions and answers on how to do that, but none seem to address the race condition between doing the `select` followed by the `insert`.

It's our understanding that a single trigger runs serially within its own transaction. But it doesn't have exclusivity across multiple clients.

**Example:**

Check if a new record has overlapping dates with any existing records:

- Client A: Enters `before insert trigger`
- Client A: Fetches records and checks for overlapping dates.
- Client B: Enters `before insert trigger`
- Client B: Fetches records and checks for overlapping dates.
- Client B: Writes new record to the database, trigger ends.
- Client A: Now has a stale result with an `insert` pending.

The Salesforce documentation says to use `FOR UPDATE` to acquire an exclusive lock on certain records:

[Apex Developer Guide: Locking Statements](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_locking_statements.htm)

Given the example in the documentation, is the following a valid (or even recommended) way to lock all records?

`Account [] accts = [SELECT Id, StartDate, EndDate FROM Account FOR UPDATE];`

Note that we're only likely to be looping over a small number of records. Think of it like a membership with monthly billing records. The dates for each monthly Billing record should not overlap with any others *for a given membership*.

**Update 1:**

Refer to: [Salesforce Platform: Order of Execution Overview](https://architect.salesforce.com/1/asset/immutable/s/e6cf2ac/assets/images/Salesforce-Order-Of-Execution-Diagram.png)

When using `FOR UPDATE` in a SOQL query, is the "lock" effectively acquired in step 3 of the execution order and then released after step 19/20?

If so, is the following true:

- The trigger using `FOR UPDATE` in step 3 will wait for all in-progress events on those records to complete before it can acquire the lock.
- Once acquired, all subsequent events will then wait on step 1 until the event with the lock completes step 19/20?
- The code that initiated the `FOR UPDATE` does not have to do any explicit clean-up to release the lock.

Comment: YMMV but performing SOQL without a `WHERE` clause is likely to cause performance issues or even governor limit issues. I suggest you do, indeed, include per-Account date range comparison, via the use of dynamically generated SOQL that uses `FOR UPDATE` on the related objects. There are SOQL query length limits, but here you can have at most 200 unique related objects since you are in a trigger.

Comment: why not use a Mutex__c custom object for this use case and do a FOR UPDATE on it? that will single-thread the multiple clients of the trigger

Comment: @cropredy... That's kind of a neat idea. It's something I'm familiar with in the world I normally live in but didn't consider for Salesforce. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: It sounds to me like you need to `FOR UPDATE` on the N Accounts that have Billings in scope of the trigger execution. That gives you the scope of lock you need to uphold this invariant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For these kind of use cases, in my org, I have a custom object called `Mutex__c` with one custom field

- `Lockable_Item__c` that is `Text (255) External Id Unique`

Then I have a service layer class called `LocksServiceImpl` with a method called `acquire(String lockItem)`

- Does a `SELECT Id FROM Mutex__c WHERE Lockable_item__c = :lockItem For Update`
- If no rows returned, inserts a `Mutex__c`
- If `UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW`, executes a retry x times before giving up

All this built with the Lightning Platform Enterprise pattern of selectors and service layers so they can be mocked for unit tests